# Update existing certain documents in MongoDB collection without remove

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new in mongoDB so I need some help with this.
I have a collection for back up. It contains documents with following data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b67"),
    "category" : "building",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b68"),
    "category" : "building",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b69"),
    "category" : "tree",
    "type" : 18,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b70"),
    "category" : "book",
    "type" : 18,
}
```

Then, for example, some of objects were changed and became like that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b67"),
    "category" : "building",
    "size" : 100
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b68"),
    "category" : "building",
    "size" : 400
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b70"),
    "category" : "book",
    "type" : 18,
    "title" : "New"
}
```

So I need to update them in my DB. Just replace, as I understood. I've read the docs about using 'upsert' and 'multi'. But I can't implement it.
How to do that?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, what happens and where you're stuck.

Comment: Also, check the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#update-one-document

Comment: I've read this documentation. But, as I understand I can replace only one document, but not all what I need (for example, 3 ducuments in one query). Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic syntax for updating document in mongo is

```
db.collection.update(query,update,options);
```

For your question,

1.
 `db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b67")},{$set:{size:100}});`

2.
 `db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b68")},{$set:{size:400}});`

3.`db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b70")},{$set:{title:"New"}});`

EDIT:

You can try out this, If you want to perform Write operation in one command:

```
> db.characters.bulkWrite(
>       [
>          { updateOne :
>             {
>                "filter" : { _id : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b67") },
>                "update" : { $set : { size : 100 } }
>             }
>          },
>          { updateOne :
>             {
>                "filter" : { _id : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b68") },
>                "update" : { $set : { size : 400 } }
>             }
>          },
>          { updateOne :
>             {
>                "filter" : { _id : ObjectId("59f18942e7798954dc373b68") },
>                "update" : { $set: { title: "New"} } 
>             }
>          },
>       ]    
>);
```

Comment: Yes, I can imlement it in 3 queries, but I want to do it in one. Can you help me?

Comment: O, thanks! Also I have one more question. As I understand from documentation, multi replacing is strict with new mongoDB drivers? So also I can't use $pull/$push in one query for php?

Comment: You cant use both in the same query, as per I know.. but I am not sure.
Also, if this answer helped you then please mark it as the correct answer.